# Get src from attach_image in WPBakery / Visual Composer

Tags: php, html, visual-composer, wpbakery

I have the following field type defined:

```
array(
  'type' => 'attach_image',
  'heading' => esc_html__("Add background image"),
  'param_name' => 'background_image',
  'description' => 'Add a background image to this section.',
  'value' => __(''),
)
```

And have the shortcode param defined here in a variable

```
extract(
  shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'background_image'=> '',
    ), 
    $atts
  )
);
```

I'm trying to get the `src` and `alt` of the attached image to display as a background image:

```html
<div class="hero" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $background_image; ?>);></div>
```

However, the `background-image:url()` shows up empty?

Answer (score 2):

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($para['background_image']);
echo $img['0'];
```